# Facebook - Query for posts shared using the Feed Dialog without 'read_stream' permissions

Tags: facebook

Is it possible to check if the post (shared using the Facebook's Feed Dialog) still exists (or if it has been deleted) without requesting 'read_stream' permissions?

**More detailed explanation:**

When using the Facebook's Feed Dialog, [example](https://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?%20%20%20app_id=123050457758183&%20%20%20link=https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/&%20%20%20picture=http://fbrell.com/f8.jpg&%20%20%20name=Facebook%20Dialogs&%20%20%20caption=Reference%20Documentation&%20%20%20description=Using%20Dialogs%20to%20interact%20with%20users.&%20%20%20message=Facebook%20Dialogs%20are%20so%20easy!&%20%20%20redirect_uri=http://www.example.com/response):

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?
  app_id=123050457758183&
  link=https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/&
  picture=http://fbrell.com/f8.jpg&
  name=Facebook%20Dialogs&
  caption=Reference%20Documentation&
  description=Using%20Dialogs%20to%20interact%20with%20users.&
  message=Facebook%20Dialogs%20are%20so%20easy!&
  redirect_uri=http://www.example.com/response
```

If the user Shares the story the Feed Dialog will redirect to the redirect_uri and return the post_id.

If I use this post_id, the app_id, and maybe the User Access token, is it possible to check (using FQL, Graph API, or other) if the post still exists (or if it has been removed) without requesting 'read_stream' permissions?

**What I want to achieve:**

What I am trying to do is to ask the user to Share a story and then when he/she uses the website again I would like to check if the Share has been removed (or not). It is OK to get the User Access Token, but I do not want to ask the user to grant 'read_stream' permissions.

Comment: If you could read a post that is not public without asking a user for read_stream, then it's a bug in the API.  Why else would they have read_stream as a permissions if it wasn't necessary?

Comment: Since Facebook's Feed Dialog uses the app_id, I was hoping that the app itself would have access to the post too. (Especially since the Feed Dialog says 'via ****', where **** is the App name)

Comment: Users (including myself) are very reluctant to give 'read_stream' permissions – it gives the app (and also the developers) full access to all private posts. It would be great if Facebook had something equivalent to the 'read_stream' permission but which would restricted the app to read posts related to it's app id.